# Quitting Mail is very slow

Tags: mail.app, imap

Since a few years I can't quit Mail.app instantly. The more folders I have entered during the usage, the more folder Mail.app tries to close before it quits. Each close operation takes 3-8 sec to complete, so quitting the whole program takes half a minute or so. How can I skip or make this closing procedure faster?

[image: Status window]

I use an own IMAP server for my emails.

Reindexig mails, recreating accounts, etc. does not work.

Comment: Use NETTOP in terminal to observe what is going on.

Comment: All I see is TimeWait and FinWait2 states: https://gist.github.com/gklka/8a628f073d4c4029e0bf

Comment: check this out https://kb.iu.edu/d/ajmi  and this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2008/10/09/tcp-connections-hanging-in-the-close-wait-and-fin-wait-2-state.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Check Preferences - Accounts - Mailbox behaviors that you don't have options 'Delete [Sent, Junk, Deleted] messages - when quitting mail'

Also, how many messages do you have? If there are many (like around 10k and above), then I think this is inevitable that you have such app closing time. Probably in this case it is better to reorganize your mails. Probably create some local archive.

Comment: Deleting mail automatically is off. All that Mail does on quit is waiting for the server to close the mailboxes. I have ~40.000 mail in ~25 mailboxes. I don't think this affects the closing time. During this period Mail does not take any CPU or network resources.

Comment: I have like 3,5 thousand mails in my inbox combined from two different accounts and my quit time is eye blink. However, some time ago I went from sorting messages into real folders to Smart Folders aka filters. I.e. all my messages are kept in Inbox and they are 'sorted' by filters looking like folders. May be if you organize it the same way, your Mail app will work faster?

Comment: I see your point, but I am really convinced that this time is a waiting on the server (probably because some misconfigured IMAP server) and has nothing to do with the amount of my mail.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how my Mail looks.
You can read more about Smart Mailboxes here: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19171?locale=en_US

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I really don't want to use more smart mailboxes than I currently do. (To tell you just one problem with them: they don't work on iPhone.)